# Topologies on a finite set with the same number of open sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I need the following for a proof.

Suppose that $X$ is a finite set let's say of cardinal $n$. Suppose that $\tau_1$ is a topology such that $\tau_1$ isn't the discrete or the indiscrete topology. Is there always a topology $\tau_2$ such that $|\tau_2| = |\tau_1|$ ? If so how can we prove it ?

Comment: What is $|\tau|$?

Comment: cardinality of $\tau_i$

Comment: Do you want $\tau_2$ to be not equal to $\tau_1$?  Or not homeomorphic to $\tau_1$?

Comment: It could be both

Comment: I think what I am saying above is true just looking at topologies on 3-points and 4-points I think it true by applying $S_n$ to the topology somehow.

Comment: If you apply a permutation to the topology you are going to get a topology homeomorphic to the original one.

Comment: I guess it is possible to find an example however $n$ must be greater than some minimal number. The maybe hard question is your “always”. Without forget the question of calculate the total number of topologies on $X$ finite is an open problem.

Comment: You should clarify in the post whether you allow $\tau_2=\tau_1$. If you do, then the solution is trivial. (And you do not not need the assumption that it isn't discrete/indiscrete.) You say in your comment: "It could be both." To me, this seems like saying that you allow the possibility that they are equal. (Which changes an interesting question to a trivial one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A topology on a finite set is the same thing as a preorder.  Specifically, given a preorder $\leq$ on a set $X$, you can define a topology on $X$ by saying $U\subseteq X$ is open iff $x\in U$ and $x\leq y$ implies $y\in U$.  You can recover the ordering $\leq$ from the topology by saying $x\leq y$ iff $x\in\overline{\{y\}}$, and every topology on a finite set arises in this way.

The discrete topology corresponds to the preorder where $x\leq y$ iff $x=y$, and the indiscrete topology corresponds to the preorder where $x\leq y$ for all $x$ and $y$.  Now suppose you have a topology $\tau$ on a finite set $X$ that is neither discrete nor indiscrete.  First, suppose there is some pair of points $x,y\in X$ such that $x\leq y$ but $y\not\leq x$.  Let $\sigma:X\to X$ be any permutation that swaps $x$ and $y$.  By transfer of structure, $\sigma$ acts on the set of topologies on $X$, and takes $\tau$ to some other topology $\tau'$ which is homeomorphic to $\tau$ via $\sigma$ (and hence has the same number of open sets).  In $\tau'$, $y\leq x$ and $x\not\leq y$, so $\tau\not=\tau'$.

Now suppose no such $x$ and $y$ exist.  This means that $x\leq y$ iff $y\leq x$, so $\leq$ is actually an equivalence relation on $X$.  By hypothesis, there is some equivalence class with more than one element (otherwise $\tau$ would be discrete), and there is more than one equivalence class (otherwise $\tau$ would be indiscrete).  Let $x\in X$ be in an equivalence class with more than one element (say $x\leq z$ for some $z\not=x$) and let $y$ be any element which is not equivalent to $x$.  Taking any permutation which swaps $x$ and $y$ and fixes $z$, we obtain as before a new topology $\tau'$ which is homeomorphic to $\tau$, and $\tau\not=\tau'$ because in $\tau$, $y\not\leq z$ but in $\tau'$, $y\leq z$.

If you want the second topology to not be even homeomorphic to the original topology, this is not possible in general.  For instance, if $X$ has two points, it is easy to see that $X$ admits exactly two topologies with three open sets, and they are homeomorphic.

Comment: why is $\sigma$ above homeomorphic ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: nvm I understood now btw I proved that for finite X there is only length 2 successor using the fact above.